# Cartoon movie about a man turned into crow who helps a girl who rescues children that are to be sacrificed

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

I am looking for a cartoon movie about a man who is turned into a crow and a girl who tries to help kids who are to be sacrificed. She gets in trouble with the leader of some sort of group of devils or demons but the crow helps her get away.

I think the girl was native American and the crow guy was from Paris and that's where they end up. I think it was made in the late 90's or early 2000's.

Comment: Hi there! This is a bit terse at the moment - could you please take a look at [these guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like RWBY (season 3 I think), but I can't confirm similarities right now. Did the girl have a red cloak and dress in black goth, and did they both fight with large scythes?

Comment: @Dúthomhas "man turns into crows" and, to a certain extent, the kids being sacrificed (from _Divide_) would match, but it's a little bit too late (good show, though)